# Cancel option doesn't work in message composer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, messageui

I have a simple question, cancel option doesn't work in message composer; I searched the API references , but I haven't found the line of code that could help me.

how I can solve this problem ?

```
 messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self
                messageComposer.recipients = textMessageRecipients
                messageComposer.body = "I'm Lost, I need some Help, Here's my Location)"
                self.navigationController?.presentViewController(messageComposer, animated: true){}
                self.presentViewController(messageComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[message composer Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99qMS.jpg)

Comment: BTW - why do you present the composer twice?

Comment: Also, please read the docs for `MFMessageComposeViewController`. It clearly states: *"Your delegate object is responsible for dismissing the message compose view controller in its messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult: method."*

Comment: I correct my code

and I tried this line of code , and seems it doesn't work

`self.messageComposeViewController(messageComposer, didFinishWithResult: MessageComposeResultCancelled) `

keep in mind I'm newbie in iPhone development :)

thanks for the help anyway ^_^